# SQL Server Update Error - "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following sql update statement

```
update logins
set active = 0
where loginlast is null
```

I get the following

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Any ideas on why i get this error?

Comment: There's no subquery in your sample, or I misunderstand something...

Comment: This query has no problem.

Comment: Your subquery must return only one row for the main query since there is no repetition to scroll through the result.

Comment: Is this really the actual query you are running? Or are you simplifying something?

Comment: Post your full code, there should be a subquery somewhere as the errors points out. Also, tag your question correctly, wich RDBM's are you using, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: try 'update logins set logins.active=0 where logins.loginlast is null'. but the error you get really is weird... except you use sql server where it should be "isnull" not "is null" (btw even in that case it's still weird if this is your full code)

Comment: Probably you have an update trigger that expects an update to only affect one row.

Comment: Ouch! Yes, @MartinSmith is correct, maybe there is a trigger behind and that is the cause of the error

Comment: @MartinSmith, you should make this the answer so you can get credit for it. I'd say there is about a 99.9% chance you are right. People don't seem to get that all triggers in SQL server always need to be writen to handle sets of data not one record at a time. To the OP, the probelm is likely where they are setting the value of a field to a scalar variable in the trigger.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I discoverd that this was the case. It was a trigger firing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Martin Smith in the comments:

> Probably you have an update trigger that expects an update to only affect one row

Yes there is no subquery, but SQL server reports error, 
because of trigger has subquery.